# Netlify page not found 404 after clicking a button

Tags: reactjs, heroku, netlify

I'm new to here, just have a question and want to solve it. I have deployed my app on netlify,  everything works fine at localhost, but when I tested it on netlify with a function. It threw an error like this.
The page not found but when I tried reloading with that same URL, It still accessed. I use heroku for deploying api and netlify for client.

So what is the problem here? Can anyone help me, thanks!

My app for anyone would like to test: http://myblogapp123.netlify.app

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a file inside the public folder. Name it "**_redirects**"

inside _redirects file, paste this: `/* /index.html 200`

Then build your project and deploy it again. Hopefully, It'll work.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the [docs](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/).

At the root of my project created a `_redirects` file:

```bash
/* /index.html 200
```

Then I also created a `netlify.toml` file also located In the root of my application:

```bash
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/index.html"
  status = 200
```

Hope this helps you =)